# Byte array is automatically converted to data URL when get endpoint is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am storing in the database images, which I get from the frontend through a form. I then convert the file from an IFormFile to an array of bytes, which then gets stored in the database in a varbinary(max) type column.
But when the getEntity endpoint is called, the image gets automatically converted from the array of bytes to a base64 dataURL. Is this behavior normal/is it good practice to send it as a data url and have the frontend decode it to an image?
Also, is it possible to not send an array of bytes, but the whole file, just like i get it from the frontend in an IFormFile interface?

Comment: base64 is **never** good practice. it's a filthy hack if some part of the communication _can't_ handle binary data, and should only be used if the communication _can't_ be designed to be binary-safe. "I want to send JSON" (or whatever) is no reason to wrap binary data in JSON (or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question pertaining to image upload best practices on Microsoft msdn.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/682240/best-practice-for-saving-image-in-database.html

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a31c367-e54e-4cb5-924f-42ef40724ff9/user-uploaded-images-best-practices?forum=aspwebforms